# String manipulation in query

Tags: postgresql

I have text column 'mytext' with such (like) data:

> [first] This is first part[second] This is second part
>   [first] This is first part[second] which may or may not differ
>   [first] This is first part[second] from record to record
>   [first] Other record[second] And other text
>   [first] Other record[second] for other record
>   [first] And finally third record[second] No matter here
>   [first] Fourth record
>   [first] Fourth record[third] Here misses second

And I have to query table with SELECT DISTINCT on part of string which is in column.
This part begins on start of string and ends on place of end of string or on place where character '[' appear.
So I can get result:

> [first] This is first part
>   [first] Other record
>   [first] And finally third record
>   [first] Fourth record

I think for that is needed to do a bit of string manipulation in query but I may be wrong.

How to achieve this result from showed data and is this possible to do with query from my .NET program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`regexp_replace`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-matching.html) like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    regexp_replace(mytext, '^(\[.*?)(\[.*)$', '\1', 'g')
FROM mytable
```

Obligatory [SQLFiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/ac438/2).

Comment: Hi mvp, I get results with your first approach, one you deleted :)

Comment: I've seen that you are using non-static second string, that's why I decided to improve it. But, look at the demo, it gets what you asked for, don't you think?

Comment: Yes, it did it. Because I simplified my demo too much :) Thank you, I can use your solution.

Answer (score 1):

use a regular expressions

```
postgres=# select substring('[first] This is first part[second] This is second part' from '(.*)\[second\]');
         substring          
----------------------------
 [first] This is first part
(1 row)
```

[related postgresql doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-matching.html)

or without RE

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.left_limit(text, text)
RETURNS text
LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
SELECT left($1, strpos($1, $2) - 1)
$function$

postgres=# select left_limit('[first] This is first part[second] This is second part','[second]');
         left_limit         
----------------------------
 [first] This is first part
(1 row)
```

Comment: Hi Pavel, can here be solution without using regular expressions because I see before that they in postgreSQL is not aware of all my locale characters?

Comment: But that I cannot do from my NET program (I think). For that I would need to create function in postgreSQL (what I don't know how) first. Kind of solution of 'Dangerous Dave' look's most appropriate if I can get it working, but I still can't.

Comment: you can execute query "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ..." and it creates function.

Comment: Never do such thing but I will try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use substring with charindex for it.

select distinct substring(mytext, 1, charindex('[', mytext)) txt from yourtable

ND

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't provide charindex function, related function in pg is a "position()" or "strpos()" functions.

Comment: I would like that kind of solution without regex but as Pavel say 'charindex don't exists in postgreSQL' and with strpos or position I don't get wanted result.